# why doesn't the xhtml validate

Tags: html, xhtml

I don't understand why this form will not validate. It claims that I have not closed an `input` tag and that I have a closing `input` tag that is not open.

The page in question is http://squareownz.org/dunkyp/index.py

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsquareownz.org%2Fdunkyp%2Findex.py

This page however doesn't agree that the code is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `<input />` instead of `<input></input>`

Answer (score 2):

You can't have closing input tags, you need to self-close them:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value=""></input>
```

->

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try to reform your input tags to

```
<input />
instead of
<input></input>
```

I think that is it

edit: damn people response fast here I see my solution has already been suggested.